# Authentication in VSCODE extension development

Tags: vscode-extensions, azure-ad-msal

I am developing VSCODE extension where I have scenario to authenticate the user to an AAD application. I tried using 'msal' library but it internally uses 'sessionStorage' or 'localStorage' which VSCODE environment doesn't allow. Is there any way to authenticate user to a custom client id?